# Issue importing Odoo module

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I'm trying to install a module on Odoo12 and it reports this line.

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Anyone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: maybe the problem is forgetting to attach hashtag.  `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add # before -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  this in line.
Try using this in your code

```
 #-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```